# In IIS, how should environment/site-specific WEB.CONFIG settings be preserved, when using MSDeploy?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, web-config, msdeploy

## Background

I work in QA at a software company.

We have about a half a dozen different web applications, each of which may require, at any given site, some customised settings added to its **web.config** file.

These can range from which Oracle database/schema(s) the app connects to, to how many search results to cache, to which hierarchy to use when sorting items on a web page.

We make use of Microsoft's Deploy package, to get the new releases installed/updated on client sites.

When we put out a new release, some of these customised settings may have been added to or removed from the given web app's **web.config** file, but using Deploy to import the new release over the top of the old one will clobber any customisations that may have been made.

## Alternatives

There are ways of handling this manually, such as merging via a plain text comparison of the old and new **web.config** files, but these are cumbersome and prone to human error.

I was reading about [transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx) and thought they could be of some use.

There is also the capability to [use external files (tip #8)](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx) which seems like a good way to go.

## Improvement?

Should our programmers be providing some sort of semi-automated merge facility for this **web.config** file? Does the Deploy package provide this somehow?

Should we be making use of the external config files, as a best practice?

Is the concept of customising this **web.config** file at each site so fundamentally flawed that the whole thing needs to be re-thought?

Comment: @BrentPabst Thanks for the info on transformations! I wasn't sure whether to post this here or on Stack Overflow, and didn't want to double-up straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft provides Web.config transformations as the de-facto way to do this.  You can create different deployment configurations within Visual Studio and the web projects.  Then when you build or your build server builds with that particular configuration the web.config is transformed to contain the settings you want to see.

[View more about web.config transforms here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: To add to this we now support Profile specific transforms (instead of just build config transforms). See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx.